# How to restrict access by using a self-signed certificate?

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I have a python script that wants to communicate via HTTPS to a flask application using a self-signed certificate.

I've created an SSL certificate with `openssl`. I want flask to only accept connections that use  that certificate and refuse those that do not.

Can anyone give some thoughts of how can I do that?

Comment: removed code tag, added SSL certificate to clarify what was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `flask` is capable of that. `Flask` only takes care of the content building stuff. It in fact uses [Werkzeug](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug) as backend while in development mode.

During development, werkzeug's builtin server supports SSL for testing purposes:

```
run_simple('localhost', 4000, application,
       ssl_context=('/path/to/the/key.crt',
                    '/path/to/the/key.key'))
```

Details can be found [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/serving/#quickstart).

When it comes to production, a flask project has to be depolyed with a WSGI backend that is more productive. There are many backends out there like [gunicorn](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/develop/index.html) and [uWSGI](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi)(with [nginx](http://nginx.org/)). If you choose to use one of them, You may want to check out their documentation to find about how to add HTTPS support.

Comment: I'd say nginx would be the easiest option here. gunicorn and uWSGI are just WSGI backends and don't handle SSL (AKAIK)

Comment: The context my app is going to run is intended for internal access only, so werkzeug is fine. I think modifying werkzeug could be a solution because doing what I want from scratch is like reinventing the wheel. Is out there anything that you know (papers, websites,...) that could help me to achieve this?

Comment: Werkzeug's builtin server supports SSL for testing purposes. I've edit my answer to make it clear.